# AJAX update variable in html django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I'm trying to update a variable in an html page after it has been updated using an AJAX call:

```
    {% for q in questions %}
             {% if qdelete == forloop.counter %}
            <div align= Center>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="qyesbtn" name="qyesbtn" value="qyesbtn_{{q.id}}">Yes &raquo;</button>
            </div>
            <div align= Center>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="qnobtn" name="qnobtn" value="qnobtn">No &raquo;</button> 
            </div>
             {% else %}
             <button type="button" id="qbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" name="qid" value="{{forloop.counter}}" onclick="SetDeleteNum({{forloop.counter}})">Delete &raquo;</button>
             {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
<script>
function SetDeleteNum(d) {
    var num = -1
    num =  d
    console.log('num: '+num)
    var page = $(this)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'home' %}",
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
            'qid': num

        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          console.log('aa'+JSON.stringify(data))
            page.html(data);

        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log('err: '+JSON.stringify(e))
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

The value qdelete should be updated to 'num' after the AJAX call but it is still as before although I can see from the logs that the qdelete has the new value assigned but it simply not displayed in the page. I also tried to put the new 'data' in the new html using the line 'page.html(data);' but no luck. Any idea?

Comment: What is in the `data` received from the server ?

Comment: There's an important distinction between your JS variables and your django/template context variables. You should think of django template rendering as a separate world from your javascript. What is the goal here? To have that delete button show a "Yes/No" set of confirmation buttons?

Comment: @wholevinski: the goal is to show the Y/N buttons if qdelete is a number (the number is the same in the for loop, so if qdelete=1 only the line number 1 has Y/N buttons the others has still the other button)

Comment: So qdelete is effectively gone from the front-end after the page renders. The simplest approach I can think of now is to associate your Yes/No buttons and the Delete button with that index. Possibly add an attribute which makes them queryable by index. Then, query the DOM for them and toggle them to be hidden or not.

Comment: I don't understand...

Comment: The python variables you're using are placed into something called a context. That context is then used to render an HTML page, and it takes into account any templating language constructs you've used (if statements, for loops, etc). The thing that pops out of that process is straight HTML, with all of those for loops and if statements gone. From that point on, you're going to have to manipulate the HTML page that's been rendered using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution simply I put ids on all the buttons:

```
<div align= Center id="qbtn_{{forloop.counter}}" style="display:block">
             <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary btn-large" name="qid" value="{{forloop.counter}}" onclick="SetDeleteNum({{forloop.counter}})">Delete &raquo;</button>
             </div>
            <div align= Center id="ybtn_{{forloop.counter}}" style="display:none">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="qyesbtn" name="qyesbtn" value="qyesbtn_{{q.id}}">Yes &raquo;</button>
            </div>
            <div align= Center id="nbtn_{{forloop.counter}}" style="display:none">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="qnobtn" name="qnobtn" value="qnobtn" onclick="SetDeleteNum({{forloop.counter}})">No &raquo;</button> 
            </div>
```

and then I show/hide the buttons according to the counter value:

```
function SetDeleteNum(d) {
    var num = -1
    num =  d
    console.log('num: '+num)        //code to refresh the page
    //var page_y = $( document ).scrollTop();
    //window.location.href = window.location.href + '?page_y=' + page_y;
    //var div = $(this).getElementById("qbtn_"+num.toString())
    console.log('dd: '+'-')
    div_q = document.getElementById("qbtn_"+num.toString())
    div_y = document.getElementById("ybtn_"+num.toString())
    div_n = document.getElementById("nbtn_"+num.toString())
    //div.disabled = true
    if(div_q.style.display == 'block'){
        div_y .style.display = 'block';
        div_n .style.display = 'block';
        div_q.style.display = 'none';
    }   
    else{
        div_q.style.display = 'block';
        div_n .style.display = 'none';
        div_y .style.display = 'none';
    }
    }
```

hope it helps to others

Comment: Nice job! This was pretty much what I was getting at.